# Guess the movie using the image

Tags: visual, rebus, steganography, movies

**The image:**

[image: the image]

Do not overthink things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

> [Pizza Time](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10186082/)

Because

> I can see a pizza and a hourglass

Comment: Could you elaborate? Where/how do you see it?

Comment: @samm82 I was sitting at my laptop and the screen was tilted back, so I could see it instantly. I have no idea what kind of algoritm is used. And it was explicitly stated: Do not overthink things :)

Comment: @samm82 if you just gaze at it relaxedly you can pick out the dark outlines (even the slice missing). And now I see that tipping my screen back does increase the contrast.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like the [TV screen from *Poltergeist* (1982)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084516/mediaviewer/rm918294016?ref_=ttmi_mi_all_pos_155)

Comment: In the image you linked to the screen doesn't seem to have any colour red, while the image here has some.